# Can someone explain why the moment of inertia of a circular current carrying loop is $\frac12 mr^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Can someone explain why the moment of inertia of this circular current carrying ring about its diameter is $\frac12 mr^2$?

[image: Circular current carrying loop]

Comment: Hi Latha. There must be a thousand web pages giving the calculation for the moment of inertia of a ring. Was it that you didn't realise $\frac12 mr^2$ is the MOI about a diameter not about its axis?

Comment: [Here's a link deriving the formula for the moment of inertia of a ring about its diameter.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479270/moment-of-inertia-of-the-ring-through-the-diameter) The fact that it carries a current doesn't affect the MoI at all.

Answer (score 1):

Because the moment of inertia is the 2nd moment of the mass distribution, which is fixed at $mr^2$ (all mass is at a distance of $||r||$).

If you pick any 2 orthogonal axes (in the plane of the ring), then that moment is divided between them equally (by symmetry), so for one axis it has to be $\frac 1 2 mr^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia of the ring around the axis perpendicular to the ring going through its center is $mr^2$. Let this be $I_z$.

Let the moment of inertia of the ring around the x- and y-axes be $I_x$ and $I_y$, respectively. By symmetry, $I_x = I_y$. By the [perpendicular axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_axis_theorem), $I_z = I_x + I_y$. Thus $I_x = I_y = \frac 12 mr^2$.